# Django not connecting to PostGres on Elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup django using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS EC2. However, trying to run the application gives me the following errors in the log file

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
  conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
  django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2015-06-08T04:52:45.155Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_SportsGullyRest/Command 01_migrate] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-08T04:52:45.155Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_SportsGullyRest] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-08T04:52:45.155Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-08T04:52:45.191Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-08T04:52:45.191Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-08T04:52:45.191Z] INFO  [5434]  - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-AppDeploy failed.
[2015-06-08T04:58:30.553Z] INFO  [5642]  - [CMD-BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-06-08T04:58:30.781Z] INFO  [5642]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-06-08T04:58:30.781Z] INFO  [5642]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-06-08T04:58:30.781Z] INFO  [5642]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-06-08T04:58:30.782Z] INFO  [5642]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
```

My Python Config file is:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "SportsGullyRest.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/SportsGullyRest:$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: SportsGullyRest/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "/static/"
```

Is there something I'm missing to deploy the app?

EDIT:

This is my settings.py for DATABASES

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'dbname',
            'USER': 'sgadmin',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be any of the following:

1. Have you set up postgres in your environment?
2. Is it running?
3. Did your instance shut down abruptly and you had to restart EC2? Check the service status

I usually have a problem with the third one and it has led to corrupt DB files as well once. I had to do the setup all over again. I would suggest you to move to RDS as it will provide you more stability or else you have to be responsible for managing the postgres DB yourself.

Comment: I have set up an RDS. My overview health shows Green. I don't know what I'm missing as this is my first time deploying using EB.

Comment: You have setup RDS but the connection seems to be going to localhost

Comment: I've added my `Databases` settings configuration to the OP.